# gdal.Warp workingType option default

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-python-binding

I have been using `gdal.Warp()` in Python 3.6 for some time now and have just noticed the `workingType` option ([see here for gdal.WarpOptions()](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions)). From its definition:

> workingType --- working type (gdal.GDT_Byte, etc...)

I take this to be the data type that Python converts the underlying data to, in order to complete the transformation/reprojection/warp.

My question is: **What is the default working type used if one is not specified in the gdal.WarpOptions()?**

If my data is in float32, does gdal keep this as float 32, or convert to another data type by default? I'm warping some fairly large files and am cautious of using too much memory etc.

Comment: I know that gdalwarp executable keeps the original data type if nothing else is defined and gdal.Warp is basically same thing as library but I can't say where this behavior is specified.

Comment: That was my suspicion too. Thanks for confirming though!